# convert nullable bool to regular bool in lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a `CheckBoxFor` for a `bool?` field in a view, however it is underlining it with red saying:

> cannot implicitly convert bool? to bool, are you missing a cast

problem is, this is in a lambda:

```
bool? nullable {get; set;}
CheckBoxFor(m => m.nullable)
```

If it wasn't a lambda, I know I can do:

```
(bool)nullable
```

but I'm not sure how to do this in a lambda to get rid of this error. I tried to do

```
CheckBoxFor(m => m.nullable.value)
```

but this doesn't seem to be retaining its value in the controller, I'm getting a null value back.

Comment: What do you actually expect to happen if the value is `null`?

Comment: What happens when you write `CheckBoxFor(m => (bool)m.nullable)`? Lambdas are just anonymous methods.

Comment: @neontapir I think I tried that and it didn't like it, let me try again.

Comment: @neontapir That'll just crash at runtime if the value is ever actually `null`.

Comment: @Servy technically it will never be null, its just nullable because I used an NHibernate tool to generate the mapping/model for a table. Not sure why it requires it to be nullable

Comment: How about `CheckBoxFor(m => m.nullable ?? false)`

Comment: I think the `CheckBoxFor` requires a `MemberExpression`, which the null coalesce is clearly not

Answer (score 2):

`CheckBoxFor(m => m.nullable ?? false)` should achieve your objective.

Comment: Did you test this? I think there are specific requirements for the expression provided to CheckBoxFor. How will MVC map this back to the `nullable` property? Does it do a deep verification of the expression tree? Will this cause the expression to always be false in the returned object on post?

Comment: I guess `CheckBoxFor(m => m.HasValue ? m.Value : false)` could be preferrable.

Comment: @heltonbiker `m.GetValueOrDefault()` does that for us.

Comment: @Bas, no, I didn't test this. When I was doing a lot of MVC programming, I used to use the nullable operator this way. You're right, in some use cases,  it might not be the best approach.

Comment: `GetValueOrDefault` is the approach used by the answer I noted as a possible duplicate. For a Boolean, these two approaches should be equivalent.

Comment: @bas right, but only because default for `bool` is false. But right, your comment's code is much more compact ;)